# Publishing Android library that needs dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm building Android library project in order to export it as `aar` SDK package. Inside my library I have `build.gradle` with "regular" dependencies such as:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
}
```

So when the user of the SDK imports the `aar` file, he need manually to add these dependencies in his app project.

Where are the problems? When there are version conflicts with the dependencies, for example with the `play-services`:

1. The SDK compiled with `play-services:6.+` but the user app project already uses `play-services:8.+`
2. Vice versa

When this happens - There are bugs: From name conflicts to unknown methods & symbols.

The solution of "Both should use the newest" sometimes not ideal because we all know the issues of upgrading to new `jar` causing bugs so we stick with the older...

How I can handle this situation so if I export my SDK I always know put exact instructions for the user how he should configure his `build.gradle` script? Because I don't want the user to modify dependencies he already uses. Alternatively - for the SDK publisher it's not feasible to cover all user options and publish accordingly variants of SDK versions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aar file **doesn't contain** the transitive (nested) dependencies.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo
you have to specify the dependencies **also** in your project.

Using a **maven repository** (you have to publish the library in a private or public maven repo), you will not have the same issue.

In this case, gradle **downloads** the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

Comment: Thanks, but what will happen when the user project already uses lets say some jar from the dependency list with newer/older version relatively to what my SDK needs? This is the problem. because my project cannot work with the newer (in case his project uses the newer) or his app cannot work with the newer (in case my sdk needs the newer).

Comment: It depends. Using gradle it handles for you if you are using different versions of the same lib. Using jars you will have issues. In any case you should highlight that the lib can't work with the newer  libraries.

Comment: So to conclude: Yes, I "will have issues" and I must to supply clarification for this. What about putting my dependent jars in local `lib` folder and specify the `build` script to compile it inside the `aar` as local classes in the `jar` inside the `aar`?

Comment: Where it is possible I would avoid the jar files using gradle and maven. But it is a personal opinion.

Comment: The point is - If I specify something like "look, if you want to use my SDK, you also need 1,2,3...". It's good when you are Google inc. It's less effective if you have your first SDK customer and you want make things as simple as possible without raising new conditions for your customer already working SW. Because in real world he will say: Know what? If I need to make so many changes - I'm giving up with your SDK...

Comment: You can provide a simple doc to your customers with all the info to add your library in a project.

Comment: That's the point - It's too much details when you are making your first steps as product. Who has today time to: 1. read docs 2. make changes in the already working SW, changes that may cause further SW changes... People want 1 row `compile X` and that's all.

Comment: In this case you have to spend time to update your library with the latest google dependencies.